# Swapping pointers vs swapping pointers to pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have implemented a simple linked list, and I want to swap nodes.

```
struct Node{
    Node(int a):val(a){};
    int val;
    Node *next;
};

class L{
public:
    void swapL( int a , int b){
        Node **one = &head;
        Node **two = &head;
        while( one ){
            if( (*one) -> val == a ){
                break;
            }
            one = &((*one) -> next);
        }

        while( two ){
            if( (*two )-> val == a ){
                break;
            }
            two = &((*two ) -> next);
        }
        cout << "Val one " << (*one)  << endl;
        cout << "Val two " << (*two)  << endl;
        swap( *one , *two);
    }
    void addLink( int a ){
        if( !head ){
            head = tail = new Node(a);
            return;
        }
        Node *tmp = new Node(a);
        tail -> next = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
    }
    Node *head = nullptr;
    Node *tail = nullptr;

    void print(){
        Node *tmp = head;
        while(tmp){
            cout << tmp -> val << endl;
            tmp = tmp -> next;
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    L l;
    l.addLink(1);
    l.addLink(2);
    l.addLink(3);
    l.addLink(4);
    l.addLink(5);
    l.swapL(1 , 5);
    l.print();
    return 0;
}
```

My question is about swapping. in `swapL()`, I declared a pointer that points to a pointer that points to the type `Node`.

I iterate until the condition is set. Eventually `one` will point to a pointer that points to the pointer that has `val` equal to `a`, and `two` that has value of `b`.

On the last line of the function, I use

```
swap(*one , *two);
```

Which says move the value in address in memory that `one` points to into  address in memory that `two` points to and vice versa. So after this, `two` points to pointer that points to node with value of `b`. But why are also nodes in linked list swapped? We changed only pointer to pointers not value of pointed pointers itself.

I understand if I used just `*one` and `*two`, just pointer no pointer to pointer.

What's going on here?

Comment: Why all of these raw pointers actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was just playing around and found something i quite do not understand.

Comment: You can run that code in your debugger to see how it behaves, and how variable values are changed.

Comment: Reduce pointers to pointers by passing pointers by reference.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i do not quite understand what you mean , this code works as it should , my question is why :)